# I load the store/model but the list is emty in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, store

I load a data, it is from a rest API:

```
Ext.ModelManager.getModel('Test.model.DogDetails').load(12);
```

Yes, it is loaded. I can see `api.example.com/dogdetails/12` in the network events. It has one dog ("array").

I have list inside a container:

```
Ext.define('Test.view.DogDetails', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'DogDetails',
    //singleton: true,
    config: {
        layout: 'fit',
        items : [
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                store: 'DogDetails',
                itemTpl: [
                    '{NAME}'
                ],
                variableHeights: true
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Then, I click a button to pop up the view.

```
this.dogD = Ext.widget('DogDetails', {
    title: "hghgh"
});
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('dogNavigationView')[0].push(this.dogD);
```

And the list is emty. I have checked the list's store and it says that the store has never been loaded. So, it seems that this is not the way how to load the data. But then I have tried to `Test.view.DogDetails.items.items[0].getStore().getModel().load(12);` This one loads the store that I want but it doesn't load the `api.example.com/dogdetails/12`, it loads `api.example.com/dogdetails/` which is emty. Also I have tried to use singelton, but then `Test.view.DogDetails.items.items[0]` doesn't exists.

What is the proper way to pop up a list with a store??

Comment: Most probably you have wrong defined your model/proxy. Put definition of its and content of api.example.com/dogdetails/12

Answer (score 0):

Here is an examples to show a list with a store:

```
Ext.define('Contact', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: ['firstName', 'lastName']
    }
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
   model: 'Contact',
   sorters: 'lastName',

   grouper: {
       groupFn: function(record) {
           return record.get('lastName')[0];
       }
   },

   data: [
       { firstName: 'Tommy',   lastName: 'Maintz'  },
       { firstName: 'Rob',     lastName: 'Dougan'  },
       { firstName: 'Ed',      lastName: 'Spencer' },
       { firstName: 'Jamie',   lastName: 'Avins'   },
       { firstName: 'Aaron',   lastName: 'Conran'  },
       { firstName: 'Dave',    lastName: 'Kaneda'  },
       { firstName: 'Jacky',   lastName: 'Nguyen'  },
       { firstName: 'Abraham', lastName: 'Elias'   },
       { firstName: 'Jay',     lastName: 'Robinson'},
       { firstName: 'Nigel',   lastName: 'White'   },
       { firstName: 'Don',     lastName: 'Griffin' },
       { firstName: 'Nico',    lastName: 'Ferrero' },
       { firstName: 'Jason',   lastName: 'Johnston'}
   ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.List', {
   fullscreen: true,
   itemTpl: '<div class="contact">{firstName} <strong>{lastName}</strong></div>',
   store: store,
   grouped: true
});
```

For more understanding, have a look at the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List).